# Analyzing open windows by title in powershell/batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I am trying to automate some processes with powershell/batch and want to wait for a window to pop up.

The window shows up in [taskmgr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ww0px.png) but wont show via the `tasklist` command in the cmd, nor by `get-process` in powershell. Is there any way to do this?

Codes I've tried:

```
tasklist /v /fi "windowtitle eq Mapkey unterbrochen"
get-process
get-process xtop | format-list *
```

I want the window "Mapkey unterbrochen" to be found in a commmand. It shows up in taskmgr, so i guess it should be possible.

Comment: Try `Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle -like '*Mapkey unterbrochen*' } | fl *`

Comment: why `/v`? what happens when you remove verbose mode? `tasklist /fi "windowtitle eq Mapkey unterbrochen`

Comment: You seem to mix batch code and PowerShell in a single script, which obviously cannot work...

Comment: Okay so [@Theo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9898643/theo) method kinda worked... Just not in my situation. If it were any other program it woul've probably worked. I found another solution which workes just fine: `powershell -command "&{$ws = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell; if($ws.AppActivate('Mapkey')){exit(0)} else {exit(1)}}"`
Anyhow thanks for help! Now I just need to find out how to close posts... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`FindWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindowa) from Win32 API:

```
$extlib = @"
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(IntPtr sClassName, String sAppName);
"@

$win32  = Add-Type -Namespace Win32 -Name Funcs -MemberDefinition $extlib -PassThru
$wname  = 'Mapkey unterbrochen' # any existing window name

$handle = $win32::FindWindow([IntPtr]::Zero, $wname ) 

if( $handle -gt 0 ) {
    # windows found
}
```